# mediaPlayer seekto(pos) when screenorientation changes error Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, screen-orientation

I have this layout, with 3 buttons one for load and play the audio, other for pause and other for stop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_red"
    tools:context=".views.Ayuda">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="571dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/ayudaText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnloadaudio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="cargarReproductor"
                android:text="@string/play" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnpause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="pausarReproduccion"
                android:text="@string/pause" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnstop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="pararReproduccion"
                android:text="@string/stop" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the java code I get the Audio file from realtime database of firebase, I want that when screenhorientation changes, the audio continues in the same time.

```
cargar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnloadaudio);
    pausa=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpause);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
    DatabaseReference dbPrediccion;
    dbPrediccion= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Audio");
    dbPrediccion.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot!=null){
                ruta =snapshot.getValue().toString();



            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.e("Error","Error bd");
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            cargar.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
    Log.e("TAG","crea objeto media player");




}

public void cargarReproductor(View v){
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ruta);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    cargar.setEnabled(false);
    pausa.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
}

public void pararReproduccion(View v){
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        pausa.setEnabled(false);
        cargar.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        pausa.setEnabled(true);
    }

}

public void pausarReproduccion(View v){
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        stop.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

}

@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoGuardado){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(estadoGuardado);
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        int pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        estadoGuardado.putInt("posicion", pos);
    }
}

@Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle estadoGuardado){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(estadoGuardado);
    if (estadoGuardado != null && mediaPlayer != null) {
        int pos = estadoGuardado.getInt("posicion");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mecanicapp, PID: 27629
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.mecanicapp/com.example.mecanicapp.views.Ayuda}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4031)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3986)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4754)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4693)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
    at com.example.mecanicapp.views.Ayuda.onPause(Ayuda.java:124)
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7329)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1465)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3986) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4754) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4693) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have tried many things but nothing works, any help?

Comment: Why do you release the media player in onPause?

Comment: sorry it was something I tried but I forget to delete